# Changing a macro's default icon

Tags: excel, excel-2007, openxml, excel-2010

The default icon of any macro, whether you add it to the Quick Access Toolbar or to the Ribbon, looks like this: [image: Macro icon]. Is there a way to change it before assigning it to a button? Maybe by editing the **customUI.xml** inside the Add-in's .xlam file (after renaming it to a .zip file)? **customUI.xml** allows you to choose amongst 2400 hidden icons which aren't visible in Excel's options, that's what make this file interesting (more info [here](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/07/17/add-buttons-to-the-quick-access-toolbar-and-customize-button-images.aspx) and [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm)).

Note that I don't want to change the default macro icon, only **my** macro's default icon in order to differentiate it from the others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in Excel 2010 you need to go to File ->

and do the following[image: macro]

Comment: Hi, Pynner. This I know, but the Rename button only allows you to choose among a small portion of the available icons. Using customUI.xml, you can specify an icon among 2400 icons which aren't visible in the "Rename" dialog, but I don't know how to specify a macro's default icon using this file.

Comment: Also, I want to change the macro's default icon, not the button's icon. It would be a suggested icon that the user could change if he wants to.